# Wronskian matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

So here is the [link](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ekb514/M1M2.pdf) to my problem, which i've copied here:

> A set is linearly independent $\iff$ $\det(W)\neq0$
>
> *Proof.* First $\det(W)\neq 0 \implies$ linear independence:
>
> By contradiction. Assume our vectors are linearly dependent. Then $\exists c_i \neq 0$ such that
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^k c_i\cdot y_i(x)=0$$
>
> Taking derivatives:
>
> $$\left. \begin{matrix} \sum_{i=1}^k c_i y_i=0 \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^k c_i y_i^{(k-1)}=0\end{matrix} \right \} k~\text{equations}$$
>
> $\exists \vec{c}\neq 0_v; W(x)\vec{x}=0_v \implies \det(W)=0$ So by the contrapositive: $\det(W)\neq 0 \implies$ linear independence.

On page 15 at the top between where it says "Taking derivatives: ..." and "So by the contrapositive..." I don't understand the line in between. Could someone please explain the logic in a bit more depth than the notes do?

Comment: I'm assuming this got downvoted because of the "I don't know how to write matrices in latex." So, rather than downvote, I'll pass along some helpful links for you: 

1. A site that will help you to construct things like matrices very simply https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

2. A link to the mathjax basics here on stack exchange
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the link David, I'll have a look now. Also big thank you to projectile for the edit!

Comment: @mrnovice You're welcome. Is it all correct?

Comment: Yes although it's been pointed out there is a typo in the 2nd last line in that it should be W(x)*c rather than W(x)*x.

Comment: @mrnovice Yes, the typo is also there on the pdf you've attached.

Comment: I think that is partially what has been confusing me so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo. You should red
$$\exists\vec c\neq 0_v,\enspace W_x \color{red}{\vec c}=0_v$$
(I don't know what the $v$ subscript denotes; probably the vector space $\mathbf R^k$)
In other words, for any $x$, this linear system has a non-trivial solution (actually the same for all $x$), which implies the determinant $\det W(x)$ is $0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Ok now I follow the proof, thank you